# How to fetch duplicate records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have the given below request, I need to get the same record at two(based on comma separate string) times in mongodb, Now I used $in command. $in not return the duplicate records.

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/getRecordByID/_id1,_id1,_id2,_id4
```

Example:

```
{ _id : _id1, _id : _id1,_id : _id2,_id : _id4} //need like this
```

How can we achieve this, Please let me know the way of approch.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default `_id` is unique, you cannot have duplicate records. Is it with another field?

Comment: No I have only array of _id's.

Comment: Sample document and expected output?